# SQL hot to ger a count of swaps for column with two possible values

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have next table, and i want get count of swaps (one -> two, two -> one) for column value.
column "value"  have only two possble values : one / two.
DB is clickhouse

```
time                        value

2022-09-19 04:03:06.845     one
2022-09-19 04:03:06.846     two
2022-09-19 04:03:08.055     two
2022-09-19 04:03:08.141     one
2022-09-19 04:03:08.160     one
2022-09-19 04:03:08.258     one
2022-09-19 04:03:08.757     two
2022-09-19 04:03:08.983     two
2022-09-19 04:03:12.051     two
2022-09-19 04:03:12.785     two
2022-09-19 04:03:12.860     one
```

So in this case we should get 4 count of swaps

```
count(*)
4
```

---

```sql
create table gsegsdhfhdgfhgdfhdjhhjghjh(time DateTime64,  value String) 
Engine = Memory as
select * from values (
('2022-09-19 04:03:06.845','one'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:06.846','two'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:08.055','two'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:08.141','one'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:08.160','one'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:08.258','one'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:08.757','two'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:08.983','two'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:12.051','two'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:12.785','two'),
('2022-09-19 04:03:12.860','one'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT arrayCount(j -> (j != 0), arrayDifference(arraySort(i -> (i.1), groupArray((time, if(value = 'one', 1, 2)))).2)) AS res
FROM gsegsdhfhdgfhgdfhdjhhjghjh
┌─res─┐
│   4 │
└─────┘
```

```sql
SELECT countIf((value != prev) AND (prev != '')) AS res
FROM
(
    SELECT
        value,
        any(value) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev
    FROM gsegsdhfhdgfhgdfhdjhhjghjh
)
┌─res─┐
│   4 │
└─────┘
```

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/lag-lead/

Comment: second solution executed with error :  QL Error [32] [07000]: Code: 32. DB::Exception: Attempt to read after eof: while converting '' to Enum8('one' = 0, 'two' = 1). (ATTEMPT_TO_READ_AFTER_EOF) (version 22.4.5.9 (official build))

Comment: @ditrauth do you see `create table` in the question? Please fix it `createtable` accordingly to your table schema.